# Show the week number in the top panel of GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell

Is anyone aware of a solution to display the week number next to the date and time in the top panel of GNOME Shell?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the options in Gnome Tweaks?

Comment: Week number is `%U`/`%W` (start on Sunday/Monday).

Comment: Thank you. I have added an alternative answer to the original question.